# Automatically add tuples to the table when date changes

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

### I want to automatically add tuples to my table..

SlotTable(drID,date,time,status)  >>>> Time ={before lunch,after lunch,evening)

for every doctor each day there are 3 slots to take appointment..{before lunch after lunch and evening}

for each doctor in my doctor table(DRID,drname) there should be slots in slotTable

so my tuple in slot table i want it to be like this -

```
drID   date     time            status
1      18april  before lunch    free
1      18april  after lunch     free
1      18april  evening         free
1      19april  before lunch    free
1      19april  after lunch     free
1      19april  evening         free
```

and so on to 18th may..{ so when date changes to 12tha pril i want to add tuples for 19th may ,one by one..}

```
2      18april  before lunch    free
2      18april  after lunch     free
2      18april  evening         free
2      19april  before lunch    free
2      19april  after lunch     free
```

2      19april  evening         free and so on to drID - 10

Actually this is not schema for my project.. i just need the concept behind these..
**automatically adding tuples to my table when date changes**...

Comment: I wouldn't do this. You can outer join on a calendar table to materialize the missing tuples with a default of free.

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure that does the insert and run it as a scheduled job.  Make sure it queries other tables so that you don't have to re-run it when doctor go on vacation and things like that.